# Angularjs watch not working with array inside of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an object `{Client:[],Employee:[],Product:[],Project:[],PayPeriod:[]}` in which each array gets pushed and spliced by components through a two way binding. The main controller connects all 5 of the arrays and gives them to another component. In said component I need to watch that binding but no matter what I do it does not work. This is what I have now.

```
$scope.$watch('ctrl.parameters', ctrl.Update(), true);
```

ctrl.Update(); is a function and works.
ctrl.parameters does get updated but does not trigger $watch.

It's a bit of a complicated so if you need anything explained butter I can.

```
ctrl.Update = function () {
        $.post("/TrackIt/Query.php?Type=getViaParams&EntityType="+ctrl.entity,{Params:ctrl.parameters},function(Data,Status){
            if(Status=="success"){
                if (Data.Success) {
                    ctrl.List = Data.Result.Entities;
                } else {
                    AlertService.Alert(Data.Errors[0],false,null);
                    SessionService.Session(function () {
                        ctrl.Update();
                    });
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            }else{
                AlertService.Alert("Something is up with the select options",false,null);
            }
        },'json');
    };
```

Edit 1 :
`Par = {Client:[],Employee:[],Product:[],Project:[],PayPeriod:[]}`
5 Components with two way binding = Par.X (these are what edit the parameters)
1 Component with two way binding = Par (I need to watch the binding inside here)

Edit 2 :

```
<script>
    TrackIT.controller('EntryController', function EntryController($scope, $http, AlertService, SessionService, DisplayService) {
        $scope.Parameters = {Client:[],Employee:[],Product:[],Project:[],PayPeriod:[]};
        $scope.Values = {};

    });
</script>
<style>
    entity-select{
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
    #SelectParameters{
        float: left;
    }
</style>
<div ng-app="TrackIT" ng-controller="EntryController">
    <div id="SelectParameters">
        <entity-select entity="'Client'" ng-model="Values.Client" multi="true" ng-array="Parameters.Client"></entity-select>
        <entity-select entity="'Employee'" ng-model="Values.Employee" multi="true" ng-array="Parameters.Employee"></entity-select>
        <entity-select entity="'Product'" ng-model="Values.Product" multi="true" ng-array="Parameters.Product"></entity-select>
        <entity-select entity="'Project'" ng-model="Values.Project" multi="true" ng-array="Parameters.Project"></entity-select>
        <entity-select entity="'PayPeriod'" ng-model="Values.PayPeriod" multi="true" ng-array="Parameters.PayPeriod"></entity-select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <parameter-table entity="'Entry'" parameters="Parameters"></parameter-table>
</div>

TrackIT.component('entitySelect', {
templateUrl: "/Content/Templates/Select.html",
controller: function SelectController($scope, $http, AlertService, SessionService) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.Options = [];
    ctrl.Display = [];

    ctrl.Add = function () {
        var Display = {'Label':ctrl.Label(ctrl.ngModel),'Value':ctrl.ngModel};
        ctrl.ngArray.push(ctrl.ngModel);
        ctrl.Display.push(Display);
    };

    ctrl.Remove = function (Key) {
        ctrl.ngArray.splice(Key, 1);
        ctrl.Display.splice(Key, 1);
    };

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
        $.post("/TrackIt/Query.php?Type=getSelectList&EntityType="+ctrl.entity,null,function(Data,Status){
            if(Status=="success"){
                if (Data.Success) {
                    ctrl.Options = Data.Result.Entities;
                    if(ctrl.ngModel==undefined){
                        if(ctrl.none){
                            ctrl.ngModel = "NULL"
                        }else{
                            ctrl.ngModel = angular.copy(ctrl.Options[0].Attributes.ID.Value.toString());
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    AlertService.Alert(Data.Errors[0],false,null);
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            }else{
                AlertService.Alert("Something is up with the select options",false,null);
            }
        },'json');
    };

    ctrl.Label = function(Value) {
        for (var prop in ctrl.Options) {
            if(!ctrl.Options.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
            if(ctrl.Options[prop].Attributes.ID.Value.toString()==Value.toString()){
                return ctrl.Options[prop].DisplayName;
            }
        }
    };

},
bindings: {
    entity:"<",
    multi:"<",
    none:"<",
    ngModel:"=",
    ngArray:"="
}
});

TrackIT.component('parameterTable', {
templateUrl: "/Content/Templates/BasicTable.html",
controller: function ParameterTableController($scope, $http, AlertService, SessionService, DisplayService) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.List = {};

    ctrl.Update = function () {
        $.post("/TrackIt/Query.php?Type=getViaParams&EntityType="+ctrl.entity,{Params:ctrl.parameters},function(Data,Status){
            if(Status=="success"){
                if (Data.Success) {
                    ctrl.List = Data.Result.Entities;
                } else {
                    AlertService.Alert(Data.Errors[0],false,null);
                    SessionService.Session(function () {
                        ctrl.Update();
                    });
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            }else{
                AlertService.Alert("Something is up with the select options",false,null);
            }
        },'json');
    };

    $scope.$watch('ctrl.parameters', ctrl.Update.bind(ctrl), true);

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
        DisplayService.DisplayTrigger(function () {
            ctrl.Update();
        });
        ctrl.Update();
    }
},
bindings: {
    entity: "<",
    parameters: "="
}
});
```

Comment: A bit more detail in terms of code is needed here. Perhaps your $watch is in the wrong place. Could you elaborate the controller with the binding and the other component a bit more?

Comment: Can you please post the code for `ctrl.Update()`? Is it indeed a function that returns a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here.

### Problem 1: `ctrl` is not a property on the scope

After seeing the full controller code, I can see that `ctrl` is just an alias for `this`, the instance of the controller which will be published on the scope as `$ctrl` by default. But you can avoid having to worry about what it is called by instead passing a function instead of a string to `$scope.$watch()`:

```
// ES5
$scope.$watch(function () { return ctrl.parameters; }, ctrl.Update, true);
// ES6/Typescript/Babel
$scope.$watch(() => ctrl.parameters, ctrl.Update, true);
```

#### It's all functions to Angular

You may not be aware that as far as Angular is concerned, it is always calling a function for each watch to get the value to compare. When you pass a string to `$scope.$watch()`, Angular uses `$parse` to create a function from that expression. This is how Angular turns strings into executable code in bindings, expressions, and so on.

The function that gets created takes in a single parameter, which is the "context" to evaluate the expression on. You can think of this as which scope to use.

When you pass a function to `$scope.$watch()` as the first parameter, you effectively save Angular having to create a function for you from the string.

### Problem 2: the way you specify the watch listener function

Your `ctrl.Update()` function is just a function that you want run whenever `ctrl.parameters` changes.

What you have said in your code of `$scope.$watch('ctrl.parameters', ctrl.Update(), true);` is:

> Do a deep watch (watch changes to any property) on `ctrl.parameters`, and when it changes, call the result of calling `ctrl.Update()`, which will be a jQuery promise, not a function.

Instead, you want to pass the `ctrl.Update` function *itself* as the second parameter to `$scope.$watch()`, so it gets called when a change is detected. To do that, just pass `ctrl.Update` instead of `ctrl.Update()`:

```
$scope.$watch('ctrl.parameters', ctrl.Update, true);
```

#### A Note of Caution

Using `ctrl.Update` in this particular case will work, because there is no use of `this` inside that function. For others looking at this answer, note that when you pass a function in this way, the `this` binding (the "context") is not maintained as `ctrl` as you might expect. To get around this, use `ctrl.Update.bind(ctrl)`, or just wrap it in a function so it gets called with the correct context: `$scope.$watch('ctrl.parameters', function () { ctrl.Update() }, true);`.

#### Use deep/value watches sparingly

You should be very sparing in your use of deep watches in an Angular app (also known as value watches). The reason is that it is a very expensive operation for big objects, as Angular has to do a deep comparison of the object on every digest cycle - traversing through every single property on the entire object, and then, if there is a change, making a deep clone of the object, which again requires traversing every single property to make a completely separate copy to compare against next time.

You can think of a deep watch on an object with *n* properties as being the equivalent of *n* shallow/reference watches.

I have a feeling that may be a scarily large number in your situation.

Comment: the biggest it should get is 5 items in each array but that would be very rare

Comment: I tried the two solutions you suggested but the changing of ctrl.parameters does not trigger $watch

Comment: @RobertHolden I updated my answer to address the problem preventing your watch from working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your watch statement is incorrect. The second parameter to $watch must be a function. The following should work:

```
$scope.$watch('ctrl.parameters', ctrl.Update.bind(ctrl), true);
```

Note the use of `bind` to ensure the `this` parameter is set appropriately.

Comment: Then please show the chunk of code/html where the parameters are changed.

Comment: i have added every component and controller